# Error with dataservice resource when generating a carbon for WSO2 EI

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am writing a simple data service that exposes an operation as a resource in WSO2 EI 6.0.0. The dataservice is:

```
<data name="DataService" serviceNamespace="http://www.ds.com" transports="http https local">
<config id="MySQL">
    <property name="carbon_datasource_name">MySQL</property>
</config>
<query id="cities" useConfig="MySQL">
    <sql>SELECT ID, Name, CountryCode, District, Population from city</sql>
    <result useColumnNumbers="true" outputType="json">{"Cities":{"City":[{"CityID": "$1","CityNAME":"$2","CountryCode": "$3","District": "$4","Population": "$5"}]}}</result>
</query>
<resource method="GET" path="cities">
    <call-query href="cities"/>
</resource>
</data>
```

If I save this to a *.dbs, or generate this dataservice using WSO2 EI management console, it works properly returning the data in JSON format when I set the "Accept:application/json" header as documentation says.

If I generate a carbon file for this dataservice and deploy it in WSO2 EI, it fails to return the response in JSON format, always XML, and I have problems with other operations with input parameters (no input params are recognized).

What I have found out is that WSO2 EI deploys the dbs in the path

```
$WSO2EIHOME\wso2\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1491338652277CompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\DataService_1.0.0
```

However, if I upload the dbs o generate it throught the management console wizard, it is placed in

```
$WSO2EIHOME\repository\deployment\server\dataservices
```

and it works. Actually, if I copy the "wrong" dbs from the location where is placed when deploying the carbon file, to $WSO2EIHOME\repository\deployment\server\dataservices it works!

Any help about how to succeed in deploy .car files containing dbs's with json resources in WSO2 EI?

Comment: I think it is a bug of the Enterprise Integrator, becuse if you deploy the CAR file in wso2 DSS it work fine.

Comment: I think so. Same dbs from the carbon uploaded using the management console works fine.